# Trying to parse a div class but can't get the correct results

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to parse the div class titled "dealer-info" from the URL below.

https://www.nissanusa.com/dealer-locator.html

I tried this:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.nissanusa.com/dealer-locator.html"
text = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(text)

data = soup.findAll('div',attrs={'class':'dealer-info'})
for div in data:
    links = div.findAll('a')
    for a in links:
        print(a['href'])
```

Normally, I would expect that to work, but I'm getting this result:  `HTTPError: Forbidden`

Also, tried this.

```
import urllib.request

user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.7) Gecko/2009021910 Firefox/3.0.7'

url = "https://www.nissanusa.com/dealer-locator.html"
headers={'User-Agent':user_agent,} 

request=urllib.request.Request(url,None,headers) #The assembled request
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
data = response.read() # The data u need
print(data)
```

That gives me all the HTML on the site, but it's pretty ugly to look at, or make any sense of at all.

I'm trying to get a structured data set, of "dealer-info". I am using Python 3.6.

Comment: Have you tried to minimize the differences between your two example snippets?

Answer (score 0):

You might be being rejected by the server in your first example due to not pretending to be an ordinary browser. You should try combining the user agent code from the second example with the Beautiful Soup code from the first:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.7) Gecko/2009021910 Firefox/3.0.7'

url = "https://www.nissanusa.com/dealer-locator.html"
headers={'User-Agent':user_agent,} 

request=urllib.request.Request(url,None,headers) #The assembled request
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
text = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(text, "lxml")

data = soup.findAll('div',attrs={'class':'dealer-info'})
for div in data:
    links = div.findAll('a')
    for a in links:
        print(a['href'])
```

Keep in mind that if the web site is explicitly trying to keep Beautiful Soup or other non-recognized user agents out, they may take issue with you scraping their web site data. You should consult and obey https://www.nissanusa.com/robots.txt as well as any terms of use or terms of service agreements you may have agreed to.

Comment: Yeah, that's what seems to be happening: the first script is getting blocked and the second one prints everything but it's way too much information.  I want just the list of records from the 'dealer-info' class.  I ran your code and got a small error, so I changed one line to this: soup = BeautifulSoup(text,"lxml")  Now, I get nothing at all.  It runs but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: I think it isn't doing anything because there are actually no divs of class dealer-info on the page when it is downloaded. They are all dynamically generated. If you go to the page in question and run `document.querySelector('div.dealer-info')` in the browser console, you only get any results if Javascript is on. If you want to get at those divs from Python, you need Python to be driving a real browser engine, with something like Selenium, instead of just parsing the downloaded HTML.

Comment: I thought it was something like that.  If someone else comes along and posts a solution, I would really appreciate it.  In the meantime, I'll look into using Selenium, and try to get that working.  This was just a learning exercise for me.  It's certainly not some mission-critical thing.